# Downvoting notable community figures

Tags: discussion

I find it very difficult to down-vote one-sentence answers that don't provide real direction, or is a link to an article only, when the answer comes from a notable figure in the community, or, someone with higher rep than me.

How can I provide guidance or constructive feedback to this person - or should I leave well enough alone? I think that there a social contract that posting to SE sites leaves you open to criticism regardless of who you may be; not everyone may see it this way. I don't want to start a flame war - however - this seems to be rampant by a few people in particular.

Comment: Name and shame Phil :)

Comment: I have the [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) installed. It comes really handy, specially for these types of situations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with any content, you're supposed to be voting/vetting/commenting **on the *content*, not the user.** It doesn't matter what their reputation or background is. If you can help the user be a more productive member of the community, you should leave a thoughtful, constructive comment describing how the content can be improved.

It not always obvious to a new user that leaving a link to a blog post or other resources isn't necessary the *best* use of this site. Stack Exchange is not a search engine or a collection of links. We're here to provide definitive answers to questions about Magento, **not answers about where to find things on the Internet.**

Comment: Point taken. Great advice, thank you.